# Return if all Excel column values don't agree

Tags: excel, excel-2003, worksheet-function

I have the following data in an Excel Spreadsheet:

```
    A  B  C
 1  b  b  b
```

I would like to put a formula in the column after the data which compares each (text) value in the row, and returns TRUE if they're all the same ie A=B=C. I would like it to return FALSE if one or more of the values don't agree. ie

```
    A  B  C  D
 1  b  b  b  TRUE
 2  b  e  b  FALSE
 3  e  b  b  FALSE
```

I'm aware of logical functions like AND, hence could construct something like

`AND(A1=B1,A1=C1.. etc)`, however, this soon gets unwieldy as soon as the number of columns increases.

Restructuring the data isn't do-able.

Does anyone know an OOTB / VB solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `countif` finds the same number as the `count` then they are all the same.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,A1)=COUNTA(A1:C1),"true","false")
```

Hope this is what you are looking for, you just need to extend the ranges for however many columns you want to test.

**Update**

As pointed out in the comment this fails to return the right result if the dataset has blank cells.

This will return false even if there is a blank cell in the range:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A1:C1;A1)=COUNTA(A1:C1);COUNTBLANK(A1:C1)=0);"true";"false")
```

Comment: @Jon, nice catch, updated answer to work if the dataset has blank cells

Comment: @AlanWhitelaw: Instead of `=IF(Condition,"true","false")`, I'd recommend to simply write `=Cond` - this will return TRUE or FALSE - but as boolean values. Those can be formatted as you wish, work in all local settings - and can easily be used in later calculations...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA UDF: to make it case sensitive remove Option Compare Text

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Function AllSame(theRange As Range) As Boolean
    Dim vR As Variant
    Dim vC As Variant

    AllSame = True
    vR = theRange
    If IsArray(vR) Then
        vC = vR(1, 1)
        For Each vC In vR
            If vC <> vR(1, 1) Then
                AllSame = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next vC
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it will be a bit slower, you can also use an array formula (by pressing **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** after typing it in the cell):

```
{=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A1:C1,A1:C1))=POWER(COUNTA(A1:C1), 2),"true","false")}
```

This will work even if there are empty cells in the range.

.

**UPDATE:**
This array formula also works, by making sure that there's only 1 unique value in a range. It also still returns an accurate value, even if there are blanks in the range:

```
{=SUM(IFERROR(1 / COUNTIF(A2:C2,A2:C2), 0)) = 1}
```